# Placing button to top of Map in Android

Tags: android, xml, google-maps

I currently have a map implemented in my Android application, and I'm having a bit of trouble trying to place a button at the top of it.

At the moment, this is how it is being displayed -

[image: Current look]

I want to prevent the button from being transparent, ideally I want it to appear like this below, or even have the button to span the width of the screen and stick to the top of the map -

[image: ideal look]

Can anyone point me in the right direction in how to achieve the look in my second screenshot? Or even have the button across the top without being transparent, the map doesn't have to be in a frame or anything. Here is my code for the top screenshot -

```
<fragment xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
android:id="@+id/map"
tools:context="com.example.pro.maps.MapsActivity"
android:name="com.google.android.gms.maps.SupportMapFragment">

<Button
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="wrap_content"
android:text="Login"
android:id="@+id/btn_login"
android:layout_gravity="center_horizontal"/>
```

If anyone could help me I would appreciate it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Nest the two views within a different layout such as a `RelativeLayout`. Take advantage of the `alignParentTop`, `align_bottom`, etc. properties.

```
<RelativeLayout
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent" >

    <Button
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="Login"
        android:id="@+id/btn_login"
        android:layout_gravity="center_horizontal"
        android:layout_alignParentTop="true"/>

    <fragment
        android:layout_below="@+id/btn_login"
        android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:id="@+id/map"
        tools:context="com.example.pro.maps.MapsActivity"
        android:name="com.google.android.gms.maps.SupportMapFragment" />

</RelativeLayout>
```

Comment: Thanks for your suggestion, I've tried that but I get an error saying 'Element fragment is not closed' which is beside the `..SupportMapFragment">` part. If i close off that by putting in '/>' at the end, it then gives me an error with LinearLayout at the top.

Comment: Thanks very much, exactly what I'm looking for!